# Unable to exclude files using FindBugs

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, findbugs, gradle-plugin

I have a gradle project and I want to exclude some files from analysis with Findbugs
There is some generated code in my project and I want to exclude those classes

Here is the findbugs setup in my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
findbugs {
    toolVersion "3.0.1"
}

tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    excludeFilter = rootProject.file('projectConfig/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml')

    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        html.enabled true
        html.stylesheet resources.text.fromFile('../projectConfig/findbugs/findbugs-style.xsl')
    }
}
```

The contentes of excludeFilter.xml are as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
     <Class name="~.*\.Immutable*\.java" />
  </Match>
  <Match>
     <Class name="~.*\.GsonAdapters*\.java" />
  </Match> 
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Sample files I want to exclude have the following package and class names

```
com.tools.vo.event.GsonAdaptersGetEventDataBalancesVO   
com.tools.vo.event.ImmutableGetEventDataVO
```

Any help on what I can do to exclude these patterns would be appreciated

Thank you
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with your exclude patterns ([docs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html), [regex](https://regex101.com/r/bE5ntA/1)). Try:

```xml
<Match>
  <Or>
    <Class name="~.*?\.Immutable.*" />
    <Class name="~.*?\.GsonAdapters.*" />
  </Or>
</Match>
```

In detail, I changed the beginning of the expression to not be "greedy", and removed the `.java` part, as this expression is applied to the class name. Also, the asterisk operator always applies to the previous element, so you were missing some dots.